# How to combine two has_many associations for an instance and a collection in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble combining two `has_many` relations. Here are my associations currently:

```
def Note
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :robot
end

def User
  has_many :notes
  belongs_to :group
end

def Robot
  has_many :notes
  belongs_to :group
end

def Group
 has_many :users
 has_many :robots

 has_many :user_notes, class_name: 'Note', through: :users, source: :notes
 has_many :robot_notes, class_name: 'Note', through: :robots, source: :notes
end
```

I'd like to be able to get all notes, both from the user and the robots, at the same time. The way I currently do that is:

```
def notes
  Note.where(id: (user_notes.ids + robot_notes.ids))
end
```

This works, but I don't know a clever way of getting all notes for a given collection of groups (without calling `#collect` for efficiency purposes).

I would like the following to return all user/robot notes for each group in the collection

```
Group.all.notes
```

**Is there a way to do this in a single query without looping through each group?**

Comment: `Note.find(id= Group.first.notes.all.ids)` work for me. You can pass the group id instead of calling the `Group.first` like `Note.find(id= @group.notes.all.ids)`

Answer (score 1):

Refer Active record [Joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins) and [Eager Loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) documentation for detailed and efficient ways.

For example, You could avoid n+1 query problem here in this case as follows,

```
class Group
  # Add a scope to eager load user & robot notes
  scope :load_notes, -> { includes(:user_notes, :robot_notes) }

  def notes
    user_notes & robot_notes
  end
end

# Load notes for group collections
Group.load_notes.all.notes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always handover the querying to the db which is built for such purposes. For example, your earlier query for returning all the notes associated with users and robots can be achieved by:

```
Notes.find_by_sql ["SELECT * FROM notes WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users) UNION SELECT * FROM notes WHERE robot_id IN (SELECT id FROM robots)"]
```

If you want to return the notes from users and robots associated with a given group with ID `gid`(say), you'll have to modify the nested sql query:

```
Notes.find_by_sql ["SELECT * FROM notes WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE group_id = ?) UNION SELECT * FROM notes WHERE robot_id IN (SELECT id FROM robots WHERE group_id = ?)", gid, gid]
```

**Note**:
If you want your application to scale then you may want as many DB transactions executed within a given period as possible, which means you run shorter multiple queries. But if you want to run as little queries as possible from ActiveRecord using the above mentioned method, then it will effect the performance of you DB due to larger queries.